# Search Toolbar for my Shiny App?

Tags: r, shiny

In my Shiny App, I have a drop-down list with over 50 options.

I was wondering if Shiny offered the functionality for me to `Search` for one of the inputs, or to `auto-complete` the form in the box?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `selectizeInput()` and `selectInput()` functions. this [page here](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/selectize-examples.html) shows an example of the app and further details [here](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/selectize.html)